# How to create perfect component with grid in tailwind CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello hope you are well! I new in  tailwind CSS and have need for you help.
I am to creating a  grid in tailwind CSS.
I have created a div as parent and into it I have put all children.
Based on my task I have 4 rows and 4 cols. I am sharing my code what I have done until now.

So I have two problems:

1. When I resize the browser for breakpoints 767-640 md two last row go out of the border  box.
2. Secondly the first row with color border-secondary-400 that is occupied row-start-1 row-span-3 to be aligned with other box in the next row?

Any best idea how to solve this?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure why you would not use the 4 columns instantly and let the parent container have grid-cols-4 and grid-rows-4 as classes, with justify-items-center and items-center you can make sure that all items align perfectly.

Then when it comes to every div for itself you can choose where you want it to start and where you want them to end, for example the big bar on the left would be: "w-full h-full row-start-1 row-span-3".

There is one more tip i can give you and that is to use the grid tool in the dev tools. You can open it by clicking on the grid button next to the grid element.

[Image that i started but can't finish because I have to go :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iX2H.png)

I hope this helps you a little, if you still can't solve it please let me know.

Comment: @tomatom500 thanks a lot for your answer  I ty to it also used md:grid-cols-4 and md:grid-rows-4  to be responsive on all devices. But how I can create rectangle in color orange without destroyed structure. I am saying for rectangle on the bottom after Emila. Thanks a lot

Comment: What you could do @Mery is define the starting columns for those blocks to for example what I did in the image here: 

https://i.imgur.com/PzEFqkD.png

This is the orange block: 

<div class="h-full w-full border-8 border-orange-600 col-start-2 col-span-3"></div>

Comment: @ tomtom500 thanks a lot  I try to  do this before I wrote you  <div class="col-start-2 col-span-3  w-full h-full border-6 border-tertiary-400 "></div> OK it work good but when I try to make responsive for mobile destroyed.

Comment: You probably need to redefine the columns when your on different breakpoints.

Comment: yes I try to used breakpoints for rectangle on the bottom after word Emil like below <div class=" col-start-2 md:col-span-3  w-full h-full border-6 border-tertiary-400 "></div> ok it works fine for mobile is responsive but has problem on a specific a breakpoint on breakpoints 767px  and below my rectangle go out of the border box that hold all elements.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am sorry, the last comment I posted was not finished. I don't fully understand the issue your having. Any chance you could upload another snippet of how your html looks right now? :)

Comment: Sorry for the later answer @tomtom500 you can refer this link thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71860251/how-to-create-perfect-component-with-grid-in-tailwind-css